# jQuery $.each json object syntax, I believe

Tags: jquery, syntax

Im trying to add each json objects data into a div.

However I have some problems with the syntax.

I dont know why the first alert works. But not the html below??

I get the error: "movie is not defined at buf.push" as soon as i reload the page.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var frm = $('#searchmovie');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert('Got response from server!');
                        if(data == "404"){
                            alert('404, no results found');
                        }
                        else{
                            $.each(data, function(index,movie) {
                                //alert(movie.imdb_id);
                                content += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                                                <a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id=<%= movie.imdb_id %>">
                                                <img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>';

                            });
                            //content = '<div class="img_wrapper">';

                            $('#movieresults').append(content);
                            //$('#movieresults').append(JSON.stringify(data)); 
                        }

                    }
                });

                ev.preventDefault();
            });
          });
```

Thankful for any help in the right direction :)

Comment: Can you please define "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors? Also, what do you do with your `content` variable after the loop?

Comment: Can you post more code? It seems to be a problem with the data variable.

Comment: I have updated with more code and error description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing some other language echo's with javascript I guess.

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(index,movie) {
     //alert(movie.imdb_id);
     content +='<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                  <a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id=' + movie.imdb_id +'">
                      <img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">
                  </a>
               </div>';
 });
```

**Secondary cause;**

You may need to add

```
dataType: 'json'
```

or

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

if you are using json as the AJAX result string.

Comment: Damn this works. Cant believe I didn't see that...! That's EJS btw! Thanks! Will accept answer after timer

Comment: Another thing. The response from the API is res.json. When I only have the alert(movie.imdb_id) I get the alerts and stay on my current page, which I want. But when I have the other "content" thing. I get redirected to a response page. Do you happen to know why this could be? The response would be the same I guess?

Comment: I guess you need to open another question for this.

Comment: Yeah probably. Thanks anyway!